# How to evaluate simplify an expression containing derivatives

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, evaluation

I have an expression that is a derivative of order 2. I want to assign value to derivatives of orders lower than 2(e.g. the expression itself) which should cause the derivatives of higher order become zero and the expression will be simplified. I could not make Mathematica do this simplification. Does anyone know what should I do to simplify in this case?

Here is a simple example:

```
In: ww[t]=rr[t]''
Out: rr''[t]
In: rr[a]=0
Out: 0
In: ww[a]
Out:rr[t]''
```

After I give a value to the expression, I want the derivative expression to become zero.

Comment: Hello Alex; I do not think your [last question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/258702/how-to-evaluate-and-simplify-an-expression-containing-derivative)  was closed because it is only missing plain text code. It was closed because it is not clear what you are asking.  What does `I want to assign value to derivatives of orders lower than n which should cause the derivatives of higher order become zero` actually mean?  Could you write an example using normal math of what you are trying to do? image is OK if you can't use Latex.

Comment: ...The code you posted says nothing about the "order" of the derivative. It just shows second derivative there hardcoded. There is not even an `n` in it. That is why it is not clear what you mean.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Nasser. I have edited my question.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want older output adapting to newer input? You can do this using "Dynamic". However, setting rr[a]==0 does not make rr''[a] == 0 and ww[a]==0